# Laravel 5.3 belongsTo relation on same table shows no result

Tags: eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.3

I'd like to make a relationship on the same table but I'm not sure it's possible...

I have a table **jobs** with the fields `id`, `name` and `parent_id`. I want to get some jobs and their parent (and their own parent if they have one, etc.).

Here's my model :

```
class Job extends Model
{
    public function jobParent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Job', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

In my controller I do that :

```
$select = Job::take(10)
               ->with('jobParent')
               ->get();
```

I displayed the queries and I can see the one for the relationship :

> select * from jobs where id in (?, ?, ?)

I have 3 parents for my 10 jobs so it seems right but it returns parent: null for each of my jobs...

Do you see what I'm missing ?

---

I added this to my request because I want also the parent of the parent :

```
->with(['jobParent' => function($query) {
    $query->with('jobParent');   
}]);
```

I can see the two queries so it does works, it just doesn't display !

> select * from jobs where id in (?, ?, ?)
>
> select * from jobs where id in (?, ?)

I output my results this way :

```
$return = [
    'success' => 1,
    'totalCount' => $totalCount,
    'nextOffset' => $offset+$nb,
    'jobs' => $jobs
];
$code = 200;
return response()->json($return, $code);
```

Wich gives me this :

> {
>     "success": 1,
>     "totalCount": 10706,
>     "nextOffset": 10,
>     "jobs": [
>       {
>         "name": "xxx",
>         "parent_id": 15,
>         "job_parent": null
>       }, ...

I tried to do a foreach of my jobs and a var_dump($job->jobParent) but it says *NULL* as well...

I just don't get why it doesn't store the results...

Comment: Do a job can have multiple parents jobs? I mean, is this relation between jobs one to many, ore one to one?

Comment: A job has only one parent but a parent has several children.

Comment: Can you try with  `->with('job.parent_id')` instead of jobParent?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot **return** in my function jobParent...

Comment: But I have no result... I edited the post to explain...

Comment: The problem was that my job.id is a string, I casted it in my model and it works fine.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found a solution thanks to your question. Thanks +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out : job.id is a string, I casted it in my model and it works fine :

```
protected $casts = ['id' => 'string'];
```